# Why can I access the private members of an enclosing class reference

Tags: java, static-members, nested-class

I have seen many questions about accessing private members of an enclosing class. However, my question is the opposite.

If I have (as an example), the following code:

```
public class A {

   private String outerString = "silly string";

   static class B {
      private final A someA = new A();      

      public void foo() {
         String b = someA.outerString ;
      }
   }
}
```

I'm wondering why this compiles? I would have expected an error by virtue of the way in which I am accessing the 'outerString' instance variable from class A (via someA.outerString). I know that an inner class can access the enclosing class members directly by an implicit 'this' reference. But here, class B is static, so the 'this' reference won't apply.

Comment: You are accessing it through classA instance someA. Eventhough outerString is private, it is accessible for instance of same class that means someA. I am not sure where we "this" reference in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B` is a member of `A` and therefore has access to `A`'s `private` fields and methods.
In this case, although `B` is `static` it is using an instance of A to access the field `A.outerString`.

Answer (score 0):

`static` methods of a class can access `private` members of the same class through the same class instance. This behavior is consistent for `static` classes as well.

```
static void b(A someA) {
    String b = someA.outerString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. `this` only works with non-static member, thats right**..... But you **are not using** `this` **but instance of the Outer Class.**

**2.** And you can **very well access** the `Outer class private member` from the **(Top level) inner static class.**

**3.** Outer to Inner and from Inner to Outer has the **ability to access the private member of each other**..**only difference** is that, `non static inner class` has **implicit reference to the Outer class**, and for `static inner class` you must **access using the Instance.**

Comment: Too much bold :( And code blocks that doesn't have code in them :(